# Standard deviation for a measurement that has two causes of uncertainty

Tags: standard-deviation, measurement-error

I would like to know how to calculate the standard deviation for a measurement value $x$ when there are two separate sources of uncertainty, 1 and 2, each with known standard deviation, $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$.

I’ll give a couple of examples.

- I measure length with a ruler. Each measurement has an uncertainty ($\sigma_1$) introduced by simply using the tool. Additionally, I may know that the manufacturing process of such rulers isn’t perfect, so I could associate some standard deviation $\sigma_2$ introduced by the manufacturing process.
- I measure the the proportion of students in a class of size $N$ that answer a question correctly. There’s a standard deviation $\sigma_1$ associated with an assumed underlying binomial distribution. But I may also want to account for the variability in instructor effectiveness, which I choose model with a standard deviation $\sigma_2$.

**Thus, my question:** Is there a way to combine $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ to get the standard deviation for such measurements?

Or, what sort of reference book might be appropriate? This seems like a measurement idea.

My gut tells me I can treat this like a propagation of uncertainty task where I am adding two numbers with known standard deviation and do something like $\sigma_\text{combined}=\left(\sigma_\text{binom}^2 + \sigma_\text{other}^2\right)^{1/2}$, but I can't seem to find a source of information on this (or I can't find the right terms to search).

Comment: I think you probably want to use the [law of total variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance).

Comment: My comment applies to your original post in relation to a binomial, where there were other effects which would have a tendency to move the $p$ parameter of the binomial, leading to a mixture of binomials (to which the law of total variance can be directly applied). I don't know that it applies to this changed question, which has altered the details enough that that answer is no longer be the way I'd approach it. When you change a question so radically, you change the relevance of comments/answers. (If the underlying question is that original binomial problem, the change didn't help) ... (ctd)

Comment: As it stands, I can no longer easily expand on my original suggestion and explain how it solves the problem, because that problem it is most relevant to isn't there any more. I'm inclined to delete the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first point certainly falls under "uncertainty/error propagation" and your equation at the end will be correct for a normal distribution, and independent variables. Any uncertainty measurement guide will confirm this (ISO, EURACHEM, NPL, ...).

Your second example is trickier, since the distribution is binomial, and you may then want to follow Glen_b advice.

Comment: If I use a normal distribution to approximate the binomial distribution, does the second example become simplified like the first?

Comment: I think it's in theory possible to assume a normal distribution for the students' results, but I don't see the teacher's input being normal nor independent of the pupil population (from experience on the battlefield). If you want to check the limitations of your equation, you need to go back to your problem more specifically.

Comment: You can also check the web, with searches like "asymptotic error" or "taylor series expansion uncertainty"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you look at JCGM 101:2008 Evaluation of measurement data — Supplement 1 to the “Guide to the expression of uncertainty in measurement” — Propagation of distributions using a Monte Carlo method. It is freely available on the internet and discusses the use of Monte Carlo methods for error propagation.